# Is there an infant-equipped transportation service with car seat to and fro airports?

Tags: infant, safety, car-seat

My 6-week old child, my husband and I are taking a flight from East-cost to West-cost.  Is there a taxi or other transportation company that will provide a car seat on a short notice?  And also would you recommend that vs. bringing your own car seat?  If the latter, any recommendations for light-weight car-seat that are suitable for such trips?

Comment: Car seats are almost 100% (as in I've never seen a popular one that is not) designed for aircraft travel. You have to buy your infant their own seat, but then you can buckle the car seat in and place your infant in it. When you get off at the other end put your car seat in the taxi or rental car and you are good to go. No need to get a separate seat. Or you can gate check the car seat (a cover is recommended for that) and your infant can fly as a lap child. It will be waiting for you at the other end. Note that most airlines won't let you get check a car seat AND a stroller.

Comment: I just wanted to metion that I recently travelled with my 3 month old son. We were able to check both his jogging stroller and car seat at the gate. He laid on a pillow on my lap for the flight. Ask your airline before making any decisions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many cab companies offer this service, but remember you will need them in both cities, at both ends of your trip.

Some family friendly cab companies are listed at [Families Go!](http://www.familiesgotravel.com/planning/taxi-cab-companies/). If the cities you are traveling to/from are not listed, you will want to Google what cab companies are available in those cities, and inquire directly with them. Many cities exempt taxis from car seat law, but that may not be an option you are willing to consider (I wouldn't). It means, though, that a lot of cab companies won't bother with the inconvenience.

There are also companies like [Traveling Baby Company](http://www.travelingbaby.com/?gclid=CJXNxaKCg7gCFS3l7Aod104A5A) and [Baby's Away](https://babysaway.com/) that will deliver a carseat to the airport for you. They also supply travel cribs and other baby equipment. You can find alternatives to them by googling "car seat rental."

I have personally lugged a carseat on trips (pre-9/11), and it was a bit exhausting, but doable. I had a canvas duffel bag made to contain the carseat and protect it on the journey. You will obviously be charged for it, and there is a risk that it will be damaged and rendered useless in the luggage hold.

If you purchase a seat on the airplane for your child (usually a fraction of the price for children under 2), the airline may allow you to bring your car seat on board - you would need to consult the airline to confirm this. Some airlines do not allow rear-facing car seats, so be sure to ask that question.

If you decide to get a rental car instead of taxi, many rental car companies also rent car seats.

Comment: We've never been charged for car seats.  You just have to check them at the gate instead of with your other luggage.  You can also get bags designed to carry them, with both wheels and backpack straps.  Makes the trip through the airport much easier.